# Angular 2 - How to take a file input element and play directly to a video element?

Tags: angular, file, video

I'm attempting to upload a file to an HTML input element and then stream it directly to an HTML video element.  To do this, I've built a FileInput component that is capable of emitting the file after it's uploaded. I'm then using a service that wraps the JavaScript FileReader class in an attempt to take the input file from the input element and convert it to a Base 64 string before binding it to the Video src element.  From what I know, the result of FileReader's readAsDataURL method should contain all of the proper formatting for the file's Base 64 string as follows:

data:[MIME-type][;charset=encoding][;base64],

The problem seems to be that not all files are rendering correctly into the HTML video element when their Base 64 interpretation is bound to the Video src attribute.  Does anything else need to be done to the video prior to binding the Base 64 string to the source element?

I've tried a number of different videos, but there doesn't seem to be any consistency in what can play and what can't play.  Every video I've been working with is an MP4, so the web browser encoding shouldn't be affecting the vidoe playback capabilities.  If anybody has any suggestions or input as to what might be going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are aware of browser differences regarding DataURI length?

Comment: @iH8 I am not. Could you please point me to a further reference? A lot of my test video files are larger, so it's possible some type of length issue could be coming into play with the Base 64 string.

Comment: There is no good reference when it comes to that. But if you search for "data uri size limit" you'll find loads of bugs and exceptions to look through. https://www.google.nl/search?q=edge+daturi&oq=edge+daturi&aqs=chrome..69i57.2893j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=data+uri+size+limit You could easily diagnose this by yourself by checking the size of the files you are trying to play.

Comment: A quick check - there is presumably some reason you need the video in a file input element, other than just to play the video? I.e. you don't just want to play a video file that is on the local machine using the HTML5 video tag?

Comment: I'm allowing the person to create a post to the site that is going to possibly contain uploaded file content.  Before I let this person upload the full video and run the video through a transcoder to get multiple resolution versions, I want them to preview what it looks like to ensure everything is correct before they cost us money in storage and transcode costs.